# Creating a belongs_to relationship with a model from the main app from an engine model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I've built myself a Rails Engine that requires that the main app have a Users table. I need to be able to create a relationship between one of the models in my engine and the Users table in the main app. Is this more complicated than just saying `belongs_to :user`? I'm getting an error that says the `User` object is nil, but when I use the console it returns the right user. My assumption is that Rails assumed my `belongs_to :user` call meant a User's class in the same namespace as the engine, i.e. MyEngine::User. Is there a way for me to explicitly specify that the User class is in the main app's namespace and not the engine's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the engine recognizes the MainApp's user class by default just by saying belongs_to :user. I was doing something else wrong :/.

Answer (score 11):

In your association set the class name explicitly, including the namespace:

```
belongs_to :user, :class_name => "MyEngine::User"
```

Answer (score 4):

I dont know much about engines, but you use `::` to refer to the root namespace, so you could use `::User` I guess