# Rails belongs_to has_many relationship, main app and engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, foreign-key-relationship, rails-models, monologue

I am using a rails blogging engine called Monologue.  I would like one of the engines's models to have a belongs_to and has_many relationship with my main apps model.  A user (author) can have many posts, and a post belongs to an author (User Model).  I tried namespacing the model in the class_name but it did is still searching for the model within the engine.

**Error**

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Monologue::Post::MyApp::User
```

**post.rb**

```
class Monologue::Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, :class_name => "MyApp::User", :foreign_key => "author_id"
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :class_name => "Monologue::Post", :foreign_key => "author_id"
end
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "monologue_posts", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "author_id"
end
```

I got this far using: [Creating a belongs_to relationship with a model from the main app from an engine model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707639/creating-a-belongs-to-relationship-with-a-model-from-the-main-app-from-an-engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NameError: uninitialized constant Monologue::Post::MyApp::User

You need to fix the ***class name*** of `user.rb` to `MyApp::User`

```
class MyApp::User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :class_name => "Monologue::Post", :foreign_key => "author_id"
end
```

Comment: Will I have to adjust every instance of User in my app's code to MyApp::User?

Comment: @MicFin You have defined the class name in `Monologue::Post` of `user.rb` like `:class_name => "MyApp::User"`, so you need to change the class name of `user.rb` as well

Comment: Renaming the User class breaks rails active support /Users/Mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:481:in `load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant User, expected /Users/Shared/code/kindrdfood/RecRm/app/models/user.rb to define it (LoadError)

Comment: @MicFin Try putting the file `user.rb` should be in `app/models/my_app` too

Comment: I should have two copies of my user.rb?  One in app/models/user.rb and one in app/models/my_app/user.rb?  That seems like too much duplicative code for this.

Comment: @MicFin No! Try moving the file `user.rb` to `app/models/my_app` and check.

Comment: Thank you.  I did that and it ended up breaking active_admin and I believe it would complicate other things.  Your answer is correct for the amount of the problem I posted but there are other complications so I've decided to just use a foreign key on my app's model and reference the user in the engine.  Thank you for your help.  I will mark as correct for next user in similar situation.